# MySQL, PHP and tabular data

Tags: php, mysql, tabular

I have a semi-complex (not really, but it's not the simplest either) database structure:

`appointments` = `id`, `teacher_id`, `child_id`, `slot`

`child` = `id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `form`

`parent` = `id`, `name`, `contact_details`

`teacher` = `id`, `name`, `subject`

`slot` = `id`, `time`

As a result I've been using some multiple join SELECT statements to retrieve the data I require, such as:

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT ( ( c.id +150 ) *1055 ) AS reference_number,
 p.name AS parent_name,
 c.name AS child_name,
 c.form AS child_form
FROM appointments AS a
INNER JOIN child AS c ON a.child_id = c.id
INNER JOIN parent AS p ON c.parent_id = p.id
```

What I'd like to do is produce a table where the `slots` are one axis and the `teachers` are the other axis, with the name of the child booked for that teacher in that time slot as the actual data.

The `slot` table looks like this:

```
SQL query: SELECT * FROM `slots` LIMIT 0, 30 ; 
Rows: 30

id  time
1   2012-03-15 16:00:00
2   2012-03-15 16:05:00
3   2012-03-15 16:10:00
4   2012-03-15 16:15:00
5   2012-03-15 16:20:00
6   2012-03-15 16:25:00
7   2012-03-15 16:30:00
8   2012-03-15 16:35:00
9   2012-03-15 16:40:00
10  2012-03-15 16:45:00
11  2012-03-15 16:50:00
12  2012-03-15 16:55:00
13  2012-03-15 17:00:00
14  2012-03-15 17:05:00
15  2012-03-15 17:10:00
16  2012-03-15 17:15:00
17  2012-03-15 17:20:00
18  2012-03-15 17:25:00
```

The `appointments` table looks like this after a few entries:

```
id  teacher_id  child_id    slot
1   1   1   3
2   2   1   5
3   1   3   2
4   2   3   6
5   1   4   4
6   2   4   7
7   1   5   1
8   2   5   9
9   1   6   8
10  2   6   3
```

I tried to put something together using PHP but it really hurt my head!

Can anyone recommend a solution, **without using external scripts**?

---

**EDIT** as per request here is a small screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve. I did this in Excel but obviously, as per topic, I want this in PHP/HTML.

[image: Tabular Data?]

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please show small example of desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MarcusAdams - I've done that now.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I would try something like this. The first bit is pseudo code.
This should produce a table with all the teacher names in the first column, then a column for each time slot, and then the childname in the cells where there is an appointment booked.

`$appointments` =

SELECT
 DISTINCT ( ( c.id +150 ) *1055 ) AS reference_number,
 p.name AS parent_name,
 c.name AS child_name,
 c.form AS child_form,
 a.id AS appointmentid,
 a.slot AS slotid
FROM appointments AS a
INNER JOIN child AS c ON a.child_id = c.id
INNER JOIN parent AS p ON c.parent_id = p.id

`$teachers` = SELECT id, teacher FROM teachers

`$slots` = SELECT id, time FROM slots

Get those into associative arrays so you have `$appointments` `$teachers` `$slots` (you can add the code for that)

```
<?php

// simply add a blank child element to each slot
foreach($slots as $slotKey => $slot)
{
    $slots[$slotKey]['child'] = '';
}

// now add the full empty slot list to all teachers
foreach($teachers as $key => $teacher)
{
    $teachers[$key]['appointments'] = $slots;
}

// now to fill in the child names into the teachers slots where they have an appointment
foreach($teachers as $teacher)
{
    foreach($teacher['slots'] as $slotKey => $slot)
    {
        foreach($appointments as $appointment)
        {
            if($slot['id'] == $appointment['slotid'])
            {
                $teacher[$key][$slotKey]['child'] = $appointment['child_name'];
            }
        }
    }
}

// now lets output the HTML table
?>

<table>

    <tr>
        <th>Teacher</th>
        <?php foreach($slots as $s): ?>
            <th><?php echo $s['time']; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($teachers as $t): ?>

        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $t['name']; ?></td>
            <?php foreach($t['slots'] as $slot): ?>
                <td><?php echo $slot['child_name']; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```